Resolving for coefficients in a bracket algebra expression to recover matrix
I am going through "perspective on projective geometry", and on p.205.
Recall that the conics through four points A, B, C, D have the form $C_{\lambda} := \{p | (A, B; C, D)_p = λ\}$,
where λ may take an arbitrary value in $\mathbb{R}$ ∪ {∞}.
Lemma: There is a projective involution $\tau$ on l such that for any λ ∈
$\mathbb{R}$ ∪ {∞} we have $\tau(p_{\lambda}) = q_λ$.
Here is the given proof:
Let again a and b be two homogeneous
coordinates of two arbitrary distinct points on l and express a point $p$ on l
as $p = αa + βb$. The two points on l on the conic $C_λ$ satisfy the relation
$[αa + βb, A, C][αa + βb, B, D] = λ[αa + βb, A, D][αa + βb, B, C]$.
Resolving for $α$ and $β$ yields the equation
$(α, β)(X + λY )\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ 
\beta 
\end{pmatrix} = 0$,
where $X$ and $Y$ are suitable symmetric 2×2 matrices in which all parameters
of the first equation have been encoded. Just knowing $X$ and $Y$ is enough
information to derive the matrix $A$ with the property $Ap_λ = q_λ$. The matrix
$A$ can be calculated by the amazingly simple formula
$A = X^{\triangle}Y − Y^{\triangle}X$.
I would appreciate if anyone could flesh this proof out, as linear algebra isn't my specialty. Muchas gracias
